# Kotlin Determining viewModel according to activity

Tags: android, json, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel

My aim is to list data in a fragment. For example, I want to list X when going from activity A, list Y data when going from activity B. How can I check this?

```
if(shouldPaginate){



                // If I came here from activity a
                viewModel.getUsBreakingNews("tr")
                isScrooling=false
                
                //If I came here from activity b
                viewModel.getUsBreakingNews("us")
                isScrooling=false

            }
```